# How do I implement a "if/then" statement with buttons in Java?

Tags: java, button

So, if you can't already tell by my title, I'm really new to java. I'm trying to write an applet that when you click on a button (button x for instance) a new text window will appear with some information on it. I'm just wondering how I would implement that into my code. Thank you for any help you can give me.

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Button1 extends JApplet {

private JButton b1 = new JButton("Button 1"), b2 = new JButton("Button 2"), b3 = new JButton("Button 3");

  public void init() {
    Container cp = getContentPane();
    cp.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    cp.add(b1);
    cp.add(b2);
    cp.add(b3);


  }


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    run(new Button1(), 200, 50);
  }

  public static void run(JApplet applet, int width, int height) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(applet);
    frame.setSize(width, height);
    applet.init();
    applet.start();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
} ///:~
```

Comment: Well, you'd handle a click event on the button, and in that handler, create a new `JDialog` or `JFrame`.

Comment: I would suggest you look at the tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/ GUI's are not simple. java2s also has good examples for a lot of things. http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/CatalogSwing-Components.htm

Comment: Give the JButton an Action or ActionListener. Please do consider Googling and reading the tutorials, as it is just these types of questions that they excel at answering.

Comment: How would I implement that in the code above?

Comment: What's with the :~ at the end?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it:

1. The class should implement ActionListener and implement the actionPerformed() method. This is how you can capture button clicks and act on them.
2. The buttons should invoke addActionListener so the clicks can be captured.
3. In actionPerformed(), use e.getSource() to determine which button was clicked. Then act appropriately.
4. For this example, b1 shows the panel. b2 and b3 hide the panel. I changed the button labels

   import java.awt.Container;
   import java.awt.FlowLayout;
   import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
   import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
   import javax.swing.JApplet;
   import javax.swing.JButton;
   import javax.swing.JFrame;
   import javax.swing.JLabel;
   import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Button1 extends JApplet implements ActionListener {

```
private JButton b1 = new JButton("show"), b2 = new JButton("hide"), b3 = new JButton("hide");
private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
private JPanel panel = new JPanel();


public void init() {
    Container cp = getContentPane();
    cp.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    cp.add(b1);
    cp.add(b2);
    cp.add(b3);

    b1.addActionListener(this); 
    b2.addActionListener(this); 
    b3.addActionListener(this); 

    panel.add(new JLabel("foo"));
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setSize(200,100);
    frame.setLocation(200,200);

}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    run(new Button1(), 200, 50);
}

public static void run(JApplet applet, int width, int height) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(applet);
    frame.setSize(width, height);
    applet.init();
    applet.start();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}


@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if (e.getSource() == b1)
        frame.setVisible(true);
    else
        frame.setVisible(false);

}
```

}